# How to display taxonomy list with link to taxonomy page on the single custom post type page

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I need to list the taxonomies that apply to this post. If the taxonomy only one then this code works well:

```
global $post;
  $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'gintype');
  if($terms){
  $output = array();
  foreach($terms as $term){
   $outputnk[] = get_term_link( $term->slug, 'gintype');
   $outputme[] = $term->name;
   }
}
```

But if a post has several taxonomy items this code does not work.

Comment: It is fine to add self-answered questions on Stack Overflow, put please ensure that they contain details of what is causing the problem and an explanation for how the answer fixes it. This means it will be more helpful for other users when they can understand why your answer works and how to adapt it for their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working for me:

```
global $post;
   $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'gintype');
   foreach($terms as $term){
     $term_link = get_term_link( $term );
     echo '<div><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
   }
```